# How can I identify this Bianchi model?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I bought this bike 2nd hand and I'm looking to sell it, but would like to find out more info on it e.g the model number (it's C2C)

Would anyone be able to offer some guidance and maybe an idea of the value? Thanks

[image]

Comment: You bought it but you don't know how much it's worth?

Comment: My friend sold it to me at mate's rates after my bike got stolen. I'm now looking to get a hybrid, hence why I'm getting rid of this one

Answer (score 3):

It's a 2010 Bianchi C2C Via Nirone 7. [Link 1](https://www.cycleurope.co.jp/2010/bikes/road/c2c/vianirone7_alu_carbon_shimano_ultegra_mix_compact.html), [link 2](https://www.yobicycle.com/road/bianchi-c2c-via-nirone-7-105-10432/specs).

As to the question in the title, here's how to identify one:

1. The shifter has an outer housing, the brakes are rim and the RD is a non-shadow Shimano. Assuming mostly stock parts, the MY can be narrowed down to approximately 2000-2015.
2. Google images by "Bianchi 200x white", look for matching paint jobs. I got first hits at about 2009.
3. Google for additional photos of every model candidate to narrow down the options.

Comment: Good answer. As for pricing, I would add to compare with other bicycles on the used market. Use the quality of the frame and of the components as a guideline: Whatever is newer or was more expensive when new will naturally command a higher price (105 vs ultegra). Shifters with outer housings are usually considered lower spec than the more modern neat and clean cockpits. Weight and materials also play a role, as well as the general state of the vehicle (maintenance done, possible records, receipts etc). In my area I would say it could sell for 600-800€, but this is highly area-dependent.

Comment: @jayded-bee they were £600-£800 new, depending on spec.

Comment: @Noise Maybe so, but I don't control the market. I've seen bikes that look worse listed for more.

Comment: @jayded-bee I don't refute your comment. It's interesting how these things go.

Comment: @Noise Right, I'm just pointing out the obvious -- The market for road bikes in recent years has gotten much more expensive. The cost of groupsets alone has gone up significantly (looking at you, 105), to the point where it's hard to find a new 105-specced bike below 2000€. Last year buying a bicycle was nearly impossible where I live. Tiagra models are now 1500€. So an older (what I assume to be) an Ultegra would still command a high price.

Answer (score 1):

This is/was Bianchi's entry level road bike. Some versions had a carbon rear triangle or seatstays, all had carbon fork. The aluminium tubing was heavily hydroformed when compared to other maker's bikes of the same era.

The colour scheme straight away tells us it's a Shimano equipped bike: The Campagnolo options were usually in Celeste. I think your frame design is one of the slightly newer ones that I'm familiar with, maybe from 2012-2013.

C2C stands for Coast to Coast, the "endurance"/long distance category.

Via Nirone 7 refers to the address where Edoardo is reputed to have started his company.

These bikes were slightly more expensive than equivalently spec'd Trek or Cannondale bikes and attracted people who loved the style of the bike and the romance of the name. They are a nice ride.

They were good bikes. The Via Nirone 7 is still in production, though I haven't seen any of the current ones.

As far as value goes, that fluctuates wildly even over a few months. Looking at ebay "sold" listings will give you an idea of where the market is right now.

Comment: Thank you, that's extremely helpful